# how to use url for local images to set background-image in css

Tags: html, css

I try to use a local image for background-image in css, then ı use [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-image/) usage but it does not work. Why?

```css
background-image: url("pexels.jpg");
/* I use both of them*/
background-image: url("images\pexels.jpg");
/* this image is under my images folder on my project*/
```

I copy image path like [that](https://hizliresim.com/1P8lBu) but it still not working.

```css
background-image: url("./images/pexels.jpg");
```

and this method didn't work

it is only working with http link:

```css
background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/796607/pexels-photo-796607.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260");
```

this works

```css
 url("/images/pexels.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change

```
background-image: url("images\pexels.jpg");
```

to

```
background-image: url("images/pexels.jpg");
```

Comment: Do you have any parent folder for the image folder? You can try this ```background-image: url("./images/pexels.jpg");```

Answer (score 0):

change the url to

```
background-image: url("./images/pexels.jpg");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [answer]. Code-only answers might not be very helpful to OP or future viewers of this answer. Good answers include some explanation of _why_ this answer works and _what the OP got wrong_

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but you need to pass a right path of your local image. This is my folder structure, where i placed my images in my project & i am accessing like this:

[image]

```
background-image: url(../../../assets/images/bg.png);
```

I am using it in my child component, you need to check on what level your component exists, accordingly put the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to use the slash that you have there (back-slash)
For directories, you are supposed to use a forward slash /

```
body {
    background-image:url("images/pexels.jpg");
}
```